# Is there a reason localhost and hostname have no user in tabel user?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have in the `user` table two rows where user name and password are empty, host is localhost and my hostname. The privileges are all set to none. This configuration allows the user to start mysql just with entering mysql, but you can't do anything.

Is this a good configuration? I can't remember adding these rows in the table, and now I am really in doubt if these rows should be there. In the manual of MySQL and MadiaDB, I am unable to find my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are so-called anonymous users and are described in the mysql manual on [default privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html), meaning that these accounts are added by the installer by default:

> If accounts for anonymous users were created, these have an empty user
>   name. The anonymous accounts have no password, so anyone can use them
>   to connect to the MySQL server.
>
> On Windows, there is one anonymous account that permits connections
>   from the local host. Connections can be made by specifying a host name
>   of localhost.
>
> On Unix, each anonymous account permits connections from the local
>   host. Connections can be made by specifying a host name of localhost
>   for one of the accounts, or the actual host name or IP address for the
>   other.

If you do not need them, you better remove them, or as a minimum, assign password to these accounts.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the answer I was looking for.